# jquery checking for element in viewport

Tags: jquery, plugins

So I am trying to use jquery to trigger an event when a certain div scrolls into view (vertically).

I've tried waypoit.js, insight.js, beacos.js, onappear.js, inviewport.js, scrollfocus.js, stage.js, emerge.js, isinviewport.js, and a few others.

I can't get any of them to work. I am using scrollpath.js and I am guessing that is what is causing the problem, but I am not sure.

Any sugestions

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan`code`<script src="js/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ $('#portfolio').waypoint(function() {
  alert('Basic example callback triggered.');
});`code` For the other plugins, I used what ever the documentation said, but most were variations of the above.